# jssor form fields on top of slider - possible?

Tags: forms, slider, jssor

Can form fields be layered on top of the jssor slider?

I might want to use the content slider but have search form fields on top of the slider that don't change position even though the slider is changing pics.

I looked i think at all the jssor samples but didn't see one quite like as described above.

Thanks